# Skilled vs Skilful

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

> For example, to discover what had caused the war between them, he
>   travelled extensively and questioned many people. He was a **skilful**
>   writer, producing works that are informative and lively.

The answer key to my schoolbook suggests **skilful** as the only possible answer here. However, can't we use **skilled** as well?

(It is a CAE Part 3 task, in which you have to transform a word. In this case, **SKILL**)

The following links introduce us to a pretty similar meaning which I cannot make sense of, to be honest.

http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/the-difference-between-skilled-and-skillful

I'd be more than grateful if you let me know about anything obvious that I might be missing here.

Comment: What were the other options? Sometimes there can be more than one "right" answer but the author provides the "best" answer that fits along with a choice of "wrong" or "inappropriate" answers. E.g (a) *helpful* (b) *intelligent* (c) *talentful* (d) *skilful*. Only (d) is the best answer. For (c) "talented" also fits but it wasn't available as an option.

Comment: It was not a multiple choice task, sadly - it was CAE Part 3 in which we have to transform the word given - I was just given SKILL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He was a _______ writer, producing works that are informative and lively.

The OP's task was to transform the word SKILL in order to fill in the blank space.

But if the OP had to find a word, they could have opted for any of the following: *gifted*, *talented*, *accomplished*, or even *polished*.

Note that none of the preceding adjectives have the suffix **-ful**. In fact, *giftful*, *talentful*, *accomplishedful*, and *polishful* are all ungrammatical today.  But in the case of *skill*, either one of the two suffixes **-ed** (*skilled*) and **-ful** (*skillful*) can be applied.

Oxford Dictionaries says that **[skilled](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/skilled)** means

> **1.** Having or showing the knowledge, ability, or training to perform a certain activity or task well.
>
> > **1.1** Based on or proceeding from the ability to do something well.
> >     **1.2** (of work) requiring special abilities or training.

Whereas for **[skilful](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/skilful)**, there is only one definition

> Having or showing skill.
>
> - ‘Not only is he a brilliantly **skillful footballer**, he is also captain and leader of this Czech side.’
> - ‘For thousands of years, this has been admired as the most **skillful accomplishment** in war.’

The writer in the citation can be called *skilled* because they have the knowledge, and the ability to produce informative and entertaining works. They can also be called *skilful* because they have a natural talent or have acquired the ability (i.e. the skill) to write well.

In conclusion, both forms are more than acceptable. The answer "skilful", supplied by the OP's book, was unnecessarily restricted.

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skilled%20writer%2Cskilful%20writer&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cskilled%20writer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskilful%20writer%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cskilled%20writer%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cskilful%20writer%3B%2Cc1) showing the  British Corpus agrees that either adjective is suitable for *writer*, but *skilled writer* has a narrow advantage.

[image: Ngram skillful writer vs. skilled writer]

Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skilled%20writer%2Cskilful%20writer%2C%20skillful%20writer&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cskilled%20writer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskilful%20writer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskillful%20writer%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cskilled%20writer%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cskilful%20writer%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cskillful%20writer%3B%2Cc1) with the American English spelling ***skillful***, suggests that  ***skilled writer*** is also the preferred form since the mid-1980s.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the linked explanation. I think that they are close enough that no one would notice if you used one instead of the other, but if you wanted to be really picky:

*Skilled* applies to a person, as in "he was a highly skilled professional."

*Skillful* applies to an action or the result of an action, as in "his skillful execution saved the day."

As requested, we can observe the relative frequencies of these two examples against their opposite with the help of Google n-grams:

[skilled professional vs skillful professional](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skilled+professional%2C+skilful+professional&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cskilled%20professional%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskilful%20professional%3B%2Cc0)

[skillful execution vs skilled execution](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skillful+execution%2Cskilled+execution&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cskillful%20execution%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskilled%20execution%3B%2Cc0)

This difference probably stems from the fact that only skillful has an adverbial form: we can say "she skillfully carried out the task", but not that she carried it out "skilledly".

Answer (score 0):

Others have discussed definitions and statistics regarding the words *skilled* and *skillful* (also spelt *skilful*), so I'll take those as read.

As you noticed, M-W tackles your question with the following conclusion:

> In sum, skilled means having lots of training/experience and it is the best word to use when talking about workers and laborers. Skillful means expert at a particular job, but not necessarily because of training or experience.
>   [- The difference between skilled and skillful, Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/the-difference-between-skilled-and-skillful)

You say:

> I'd be more than grateful if you let me know about anything obvious that I might be missing here.

The nuanced difference is that *skilled* relates more to training and *skillful* to talent. Both work, but the context "*producing works that are informative and lively*" suggests an element of creativity that favours the answer '*skillful*'.

Comment: It's the same link that is in the OP's question. The extract also says *...In the sentence below, the words skilled and skillful are almost interchangeable. [She is a skilful / skilled surgeon] With **either word**, the sentence tells us that the surgeon is an expert at what she does.*

Comment: @Mari-LouA True, and an oversight on my part. But I don't think the issue is about being an expert - it is about creativity, something that nudges slightly closer to *skilfulness* than *being skilled*. That's the nuance I tried to bring out by my closing paragraph.

Comment: Both are perfectly fine, I would not mark "skilled" as being wrong here.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not saying I would - I'm saying that *skilfull* would be a slightly better fit in the OP's example.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've edited my answer to incorporate points from the comments.